# data transfer between forms in django

Tags: python, django, forms

In my django project I need to create form (`input_optimization_problem`) where user will specify how many bounds has optimization problem. Then I need pass this information to the next form (`optimization_problem2`) where user can input equation itself, specify maximize or minimize and bounds for it (the number of fields for bounds we get from form 1). 
For now I have code in `views.py`:

```
from WebCalcApp.optimize import optimize
from .forms import *

def input_optimization_problem(request):
    title = 'Bounds' 
    form = InputOptimizationLimitations(request.POST or None)
    context = {'title' : title,
                'form' : form,
        }
    if form.is_valid():
        bounds_num = form.cleaned_data['bounds_num']  
        return optimization_problem2(request, bounds_num)

   else:
        form = InputOptimizationLimitations()
   return render(request, 'in.html', context) 


def optimization_problem2(request, bounds_num):
    title = 'equation' 
    form = InputOptimizationProblem(request.POST or None) #, bounds_num)
    context = {'title' : title,
                'form' : form,
              }
    if form.is_valid():

        formula = form.cleaned_data['formula'] 
        min_max = form.cleaned_data['min_max']
        # bounds = form.cleaned_data['bounds']  
        res_dict = optimize(formula, min_max) #, bounds) 
        loop = range(0,len(res_dict)-1)  
        context = {'res' : res_dict,
                  'loop' : loop,
               'formula' : formula,
              # 'bounds' : bounds
                  }

        return render(request, 'out.html', context)

    return render(request, 'in.html', context)
```

The result is that after filling form `input_optimization_problem` it render the next form `optimization_problem2` but then it goes back to `input_optimization_problem` instead of render `out.html` with optimization results

Probably I should do it in different way then I'm trying but I tried to google and didn't find some useful information about it.

Comment: In your is_valid block of `input_optimization_problem`, you end up in the last line of `optimization_problem2` which renders `in.html` again.

Comment: It's ok, because 'in.html' is extends my bassic html page. It only includes '{% form %}' so it render the passed form